# Slack bot adds new line on message after XX chars

Tags: python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I'm currently developing a simple slack bot that will post a message each day with a list of text as shown below.

The problem is that the new line on the second item on the list is not added by me. It is like the bot's message is capped around XX chars. It works great if I copy the message the bot sent and send the same message in the channel, then there is no newline added like the example below.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Bot's message:

```
•  1 day     This is a rather short message
•  1 day     This is a longer message that will automatically get cut
when I reach some unknown length.
•  4 days    This is working due to it is a short message.
```

If I copy the text the bot sent and send in the same channel:

```
•  1 day     This is a rather short message
•  1 day     This is a longer message that will automatically get cut when I reach some unknown length.
•  4 days    This is working due to it is a short message.
```

The code that is sent from the my application the the slack web client is

```
msg = [ {'type': 'section', 'text': 
        {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': "First a greeting message"}  
    }, 
    {'type': 'divider'}, 
    {'type': 'section', 'text': 
        {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': '•  1 day     This is a rather short message \n •  1 day     This is a longer message that will automatically get cut when I reach some unknown length, but if I reply the same msg it will be fine \n •  4 days    This is working due to it is a short message.'}
    }
]
slack_client.chat_postMessage(channel=channel, blocks=msg)
```

Comment: If you want people to help you solve the problem please add the relevant code of your app to the question.

Comment: Updated the description on what is sent to the slack web client.

Comment: This also happens with webhooks, can't find a workaround, switched from mrkdwn to plain_text, still occurs.  Ugh.  Simple text alerts are wrapped for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

Probably related to https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin/issues/592 - I get the same behavior when sending from Jenkins. This plugin has a property to `formatAsText`. Inspecting the plugin code, especially `StandardSlackService.java` might assist you in finding what you need.